# Kit installation continues to stop android V 7.0

Tags: android, apk

I have just finished my android application (requires API> 21). I tested my signed apk on 5.0, 5.1 and 6.0, and there is no problem. But when I try to install it on Nougat 7.0 the below message appears :

> Kit installation continues to stop

What can be the problem?

Comment: your log helps finding the problem. Lucky guess it is related to a permission that need to be granted in run-time in android 7.

Comment: @Mouna Try to signed your apk with V1 and V2 both version.

Comment: I tried this but the same problem appears :/ and i can't check it with log :/

Comment: is there a permission to upload files other than READ-EXTERNAL STORAGE and INTERNET !?

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(118461456bytes) bitmap. this is the problem how to fix it !?